# JavaFX: Update menu sub-items everytime menu shown

Tags: javafx, menu

I want to have the subitems of a menu every time updated, before the menu is expanded. 
This is what i tried:

```
@FXML javafx.scene.control.Menu menu;

public void initiallize(){
// ...

this.menu.setOnAction((event) -> {
                this.menu.getItems().clear();
                this.menu.getItems().add(new MenuItem("Hello"));
                this.menu.getItems().add(new MenuItem("World"));
                this.menu.getItems().add(new MenuItem("!!!!!"));
            });
}
```

It is close but not correct. The update only happens after a click on the item. The menu might expand but with old values. Trials using `setOnShown()` instead of 
`setOnAction()` were also not working, since at the time of Showing it is too late for an update.

How to correct this?

**Edit 1:**

This seems to work:

```
this.menu.getParentMenu().setOnShowing((event) -> {
                    this.menu.getItems().clear();
                    this.menu.getItems().add(new MenuItem("Hello"));
                    this.menu.getItems().add(new MenuItem("World"));
                    this.menu.getItems().add(new MenuItem("!!!!!"));
                });
```

Is this the best way or are there better solutions (w/o accessing the ParentMenu)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are this Menus Children of a MenuBar? If so you definetely have to click one of the Menus to get to the MenuItems. You can update the MenuItems before the click happens by doing this:

```
this.menu.setOnMouseEntered(event -> {
    this.menu.getItems().add(new MenuItem("Test"));
});
```

By this you are updating the MenuItems everytime the mouse cursor is on the Menu itself.